# Safe download URL for odin3?

Tags: rom-flashing, odin

There are so many odin3 download websites I am not sure what is a trusted url to download an odin tool suitable for flashing my International Note3 SMN9005.

Can someone provide a link and maybe some upvotes to confirm it's safe.  I'd hate to brick my $800 phone due to some messed up copy of odin.

Comment: More often than not, the download links on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) are trustworthy.

Comment: It's always a good idea to take a look into the [corresponding tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/odin/info) :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question, but **[FlashFire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/paid-software/flashfire-t3075433)** has emerged as the "*spiritual successor*" to Odin. It's developed by [Chainfire](https://www.chainfire.eu/), who's also responsible for other things like [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount), [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) and [LiveBoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.liveboot) and is a highly regarded name in the Android community.

FlashFire is currently in beta, so getting it is slightly more involved:

1. Join the [FlashFire Google+ Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/116661625291346007584)
2. Download the [app](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/eu.chainfire.flash) from Google Play

If you still want Odin however, [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/themes-apps/27-08-2013-odin-3-09-odin-1-85-versions-t2189539) appears to offer a popular and trusted version.